# Calculating a complex sum

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

I am to solve the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+i)^n}{(1+2i)^{2n}}$$
Should I divide the sum on real and imaginary parts (in similar way as limits of sequences are calculated)? If yes how can I do it? The expression is quite complicated.

Comment: It's a geometric series.

Comment: @Hendrra Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is just

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1 + i}{(1 + 2i)^2}\right)^{n} = \frac 1 {1 - \frac{1 + i}{(1 + 2i)^2}} = \frac{(1 + 2i)^2}{(1 + 2i)^2 - (1 + i)^2}$$

since the modulus of the common ratio is clearly less than $1$. If you want real and imaginary parts, now it's a simple matter of multiplying by conjugates.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+i)^n}{(1+2i)^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+i}{(1+2i)^{2}}\right)^n$$

Comment: Thanks! It was much easier then I thought

Comment: @Hendrra Yes indeed I've just give an hint, as of course you can conclude by yourself! Bye